# Text area supports input html format

Tags: html, primefaces, textarea

I want to find a UI element of Primefaces or JSF that is similar to inputTextarea but supports HTML format of text.
Example: when we use a inputTextarea like < p:inputTextarea value="#{myBean.message}" />, with myBean.message = "This is a < b>bold text< b>."
then the output on HTML page will be: This is a **bold text**

Thanks all.

Comment: Look at the PrimeFaces showcase... please...

Comment: textEditor : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/textEditor.xhtml

Comment: Dear @Billy Hope, I just want a read-only text area that convert string in backing bean to HTML format. It seems like that textEditor is not my expectation :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can display HTML in an element of type h:outputText

```
<h: outputText value = "#{MyBean.text}" escape = "false" />
```

Comment: The question is about an **input** component... Or at least something that **looks** like an input (since it may be read-only). So your answer requires a fair amount of styling